# Gradle build - works from sub-project, not from root project

Tags: java, gradle

I have a set of gradle projects that are all sub-projects of another "master" project. I'm trying to reproduce with a small example, but have been unable to do so, and I'm turning here for help.

Here's the problem in a nutshell:

I have about 10 projects, but let's call the interesting ones "master", "lib", "end_point" where "end_point" has a dependency on "lib"

- If I go to the end_point directory and do "gradle clean build" everything is fine
- If I go to the master directory and do "gradle clean build" the "end_point" project fails to build because it can't find a symbol that was defined in the "lib" project

I appreciate that that's not a lot of detail, but we've been looking at it for some time and we have run out of possible ideas for next things to look at.

Omitting the "clean" from the build does not help. The error happens during the compileJava step. It's gradle 2.14.1. Both lib and end_point have the org.springframework.boot plugin applied.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue/feature with the spring boot plugin.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6572